# Python regex - check if pattern contains capturing named group

Tags: python-3.x, regex, python-re

How can I check whether regex pattern contains a named capturing group? I want to decide whether to use `re.findall` or `re.finditer` based on the form of the regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following approach:

```
pat = '.*(?P<word>\w+\d+\b).+'  # sample pattern
has_named_group = bool(re.search(r'\(\?P<\w+>[^)]+\)', pat))
```

This can also be a function:

```
def has_named_group(pat):
    return bool(re.search(r'\(\?P<\w+>[^)]+\)', pat))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Pattern.groupindex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.groupindex)

> A dictionary mapping any symbolic group names defined by (?P) to
> group numbers. The dictionary is empty if no symbolic groups were used
> in the pattern.

For example

```
import re

pattern = re.compile('(?P<mygroup>.*)')

if pattern.groupindex:
    print("The pattern contains a named capturing group")
else:
    print("The pattern does not contain a named capturing group")
```

Output

```
The pattern contains a named capturing group
```